TestNG. dependsOnGroups is not worked for different classes
14.05.2024 I have added group to tests and a dependency on this group in other tests from other classes. And it all worked both locally and in jenkins. But yesterday it stopped working and I get an error when i run second test:
org.testng.TestNGException: 
DependencyMap::Method "AttachmentSectionTests.downloadAttachment_472063()[pri:0, instance:uitests.caremanager.admin.utilization.general_authorization_2_0.AttachmentSectionTests@52d6d273]" depends on nonexistent group "ga2FieldsSettings"
    at org.testng.DependencyMap.getMethodsThatBelongTo(DependencyMap.java:47)
    at org.testng.internal.DynamicGraphHelper.lambda$createDynamicGraph$2(DynamicGraphHelper.java:71)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachTask.compute(ForEachOps.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:746)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doInvoke(ForkJoinTask.java:408)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.invoke(ForkJoinTask.java:736)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:159)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:233)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:661)
    at org.testng.internal.DynamicGraphHelper.lambda$createDynamicGraph$3(DynamicGraphHelper.java:69)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
    at org.testng.internal.DynamicGraphHelper.createDynamicGraph(DynamicGraphHelper.java:38)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.lambda$privateRun$1(TestRunner.java:775)
    at org.testng.util.TimeUtils.computeAndShowTime(TimeUtils.java:45)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:771)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:621)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:443)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:437)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:397)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:336)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1280)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1200)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1114)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1082)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:109)

Process finished with exit code -1

Problem: I need tests that depend on others to run only after they are executed.
Question: Could somebody please tell me how i can solve this through Beanshell in testng.xml . Or maybe in some other way?
First class which contains Test1 with new group - "ga2FieldsSettings"
@Test(retryAnalyzer = Retry.class,
            groups = {"ga2FieldsSettings", "smoke", "one", "two", "three"})
    public void testOne() throws InterruptedException {...}

and second class which contains Test2 that should depend on first test:
@Test(retryAnalyzer = Retry.class,
            groups = {"smoke", "one", "two", "three"}, dependsOnGroups = {"ga2FieldsSettings"}, alwaysRun = true)
    public void testTwo() throws InterruptedException, FileNotFoundException {...}

data from testng.xml
<suite name="tests" verbose="1" preserve-order="true">
    <test name="UI-Test">
        <method-selectors>
            <method-selector>
                <script language="beanshell">
                    <![CDATA[
                whatEnv = System.getProperty("env");
                whatGroup = System.getProperty("groups");
                (groups.containsKey(whatEnv) && groups.containsKey(whatGroup));
                ]]>
                </script>
            </method-selector>
        </method-selectors>
        <packages>
            <package name="uitests.*"></package>
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>

I want to make sure that when running all tests, some of them are executed after running others. At the same time, these tests are located in different classes.
